# Using function pointers and dependency injection to assign callback functions to objects. Is this good design?

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I am developing an MVC application. In this case the model classes are numerous, but there is only a single 'view' implementation. I need some way for the model classes to call the printOutput(string) method of the GUI when they want to output some information to the user. (The GUI is mainly text based by the way). There is also another method to display connection data which should only be accessible by a specific connection class.

I'm thinking of using dependency injection to instantiate the model classes with the function pointers they would need to call the GUI.

Am I on the right track with this design?

Comment: It's worth noting as a high level point that this breaks the abstraction of MVC-- the models shouldn't need to output information for the user; that's the job of the other components. (Unless you mean for debugging logging purposes, etc, which often goes through global logging functions.)

Comment: It's an automated simulation of a Health Club system. So user clicks 'Start Simulation'. The outputs would be along the lines of 'Joe Blogss arrived at club', 'Joe Bloggs enrolled as member', 'Joe Bloggs is training'. The model classes would be the objects that simulate. So, for example I have a Training object that simulates the act of going through a training program that will need to update the GUI with weight loss information for example.

Comment: I see. It's getting tricky to model what you're talking about with MVC-- that's not the traditional kind of thing that MVC is strictly used for. However, if you were, the model could be the "nouns"-- member, training-program, etc. Those nouns would be manipulated by controllers (verbs) like executing the training program to run the simluation. Controllers would output relevant data to the views as they progressed through the simlulation. Models themselves wouldn't do so. However, if the model had unique things to say, you could always expose a eg "stateString" method to use when printing.

Comment: I know MVC isn't perfect for this, but my lecturer wants us to use it. Yes, they do have specific things to say. What do you mean 'expose'? Make global? I thought that was bad :S

Comment: No, not global-- just that you may be thinking of it the other way round. Rather than have the model be able to call output functions (via func ptrs etc), why not just give the model a method that returns a useful string that represents its state? Then the controller can just ask for that string and print it itself. The model isn't doing the printing.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to do that because the control doesn't know when the state of the model has changed in some cases. Things happen in the model and they need to be printed immediately, not just updated to the GUI periodically.

Comment: OK, then the model should define some sort of delegation or notification pattern, such that when its state changes, registered observers can be notified that it's changed, and thus tho observer (ie a controller or view) can *choose* to update the views if they wish. The key point here is that the model shouldn't even *know* about views, or user-visible output. Models know only about the state of the world. If you want to think of your embedded function pointers as "delegate" pointers to be invoked on changes, that's fine. But don't structure them as "print" callbacks.

Comment: Ok, thanks Ben. You have been very helpful.